# What does freemarker @standalone directive mean in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I'm seeing into alfresco default modules and templates. And most of them (at least that I looked in) starts with `<@standalone>` directive. I searched it in docs, but have no result.

- What does this specific directive means?
- Is there any list of all alfresco's freemarker directives in their documentation or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<@standalone>` directive is provided by the org.springframework.extensions.directives.StandaloneWebScriptWrapper class. 
The full JavaDoc reads:

`/**
 * <p>This FreeMarker Directive can be used as the outer-wrapper in a WebScript FreeMarker template to add the the 
 * {@link OutputCSSContentModelElement} and {@link OutputJavaScriptContentModelElement} instances into the {@link ExtensibilityModel}
 * when the WebScript is not processed within the context of a {@link Page}. This ensures that any dependency files are 
 * loaded into the page.</p>
 * <p>TODO: Currently this only outputs the JS and CSS deferred content model elements. This could be further enhanced to add
 * additional content elements that set up the structure of a page</p> 
 * 
 * @author David Draper
 */`

There is no complete list of all the FreeMarker directives - either part of FreeMarker, Surf or Alfresco - that I am aware of.